# Java 8 Remove 1 List from Other

Tags: java, list, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have two list of different Objects.

```
class School {
    private String schoolName;
    private String location;
    private String pinCode;
    private String rating;
}

class World {
    private String schoolName;
    private String location;
    private String country;
    private String region;
}
```

I want to remove the list of School objects from List of World objects based on `schoolName` and `location`. I cannot use `equals` and `hashCode` methods on those two fields as it is creating some other problem. Please help me how it can be done using streams.

Comment: It sounds like your “some other problem” is your actual problem.

Comment: What is your requirement? "Based on `schoolName` and `location`" is really vague. Also, what is "some other problem"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter`:

```
worldList.stream()
    .filter(world -> schoolList.stream()
        .anyMatch(school -> world.getSchoolName().equals(school.getSchoolName())
                         && world.getLocation().equals(school.getLocation())
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```